# How to best map vector tiles in OL3 with missing zoom levels?

Tags: node.js, openlayers-3

I'm basically doing the same as https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html?q=mvt except I'm serving up a custom map with a NodeJS web server with a data set based off of OSM.

I've merged the data so I have the whole world at 0-8 zoom levels and parts of the world that are more important at 0-14 zoom levels all as mbtiles. Here is my basic layer definition:

```
new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      overlaps: false,
      attributions: "© <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>" +
        "OpenStreetMap contributors</a>",
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 14}),
      tilePixelRatio: 16,
      url: "/maptiles/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf"
    }),
    style: createMapboxStreetsV6Style()
  });
```

Previously I was using a bit of a hack with a vector source and vector layers with GEOjson data. I have several problems with the new method that OL3 seems to be moving towards:

1. If I set it to zoom level 14 as the max then as you pan around it will just request zoom level 14 and not request 8 that may only be available in that area. If I try to return the 8th zoom level data from the web server, then obviously the x and y are off and you get bad data.
2. The other issue I have is before since it was vector data it didn't matter how much you zoomed in, it still looked okay and I guess was re-rendered. Now, if I zoom past zoom level 8 anywhere that doesn't have more than that (even if I set maxzoom to 8), it just gets blurry like a PNG tile would. It seems like there should still be a way to have it redraw the same vector data. After all that's half the point of using vector data and not PNGs.

[Blurry Image with max zoom level 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSahF.png)

Any help and ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your first issue, the key to reusing tiles for different zoom levels is to define a custom tile grid with `new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid()` instead of `ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()`. Depending on how you organise your zoom levels, you may also need a custom `tileUrlFunction` configured on the `ol.source.VectorTile`, to translate tile grid zoom levels (which are always 0,1,2,...) to the zoom levels your tile set uses.

Your second issue can be simply be resolved by configuring the `ol.layer.VectorTile` with `renderMode: 'vector'`.

Both techniques are shown in the https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles-advanced.html example. Your tile grid configuration will be a bit different though.

Comment: I don't quite follow how the custom tile grid is supposed to help. I can't exactly know what resolutions I need for different zoom levels cause it depends on where in the world you are. It kind of makes more sense that I may need a custom `tileUrlFunction` to request a tile and fallback to zoom level 8 if it fails or somehow check where I'm at.

Regardless even if I set it to `renderMode: 'vector'` with max zoom level 8 it still is blurry and doesn't appear to re-render. I've added a screen shot showing this.

Comment: It looks like you meant the layer and not the source. The problem with that I've found is it looks terrible. After looking at it some more I think I've determined that it looks pretty bad mostly cause there's not sufficient points at the zoom levels to really not be pretty jagged.